# Using Common Table Expression and IF EXISTS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running a query similar to

```
DECLARE @VARIABLE NVARCHAR(50) = 'VALUE';

WITH MYCTE_TABLE (Column1,Column2)
AS 
    SELECT 
        (ColumnA, Column B 
    FROM 
        SomeTable 
    WHERE 
        ColumnA = SomeValue)

    IF EXISTS(SELECT ColumnZ FROM AnotherTable WHERE Columnz = SomeNumbers)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM MYCTE_TABLE
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        MYSUBQUERY2
    END
...
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF'.

Each subquery works well when run independently. It seems the use of a common table expression before the IF EXISTS is causing the issue.

Any help please?

Comment: A Common Table Expression is not a subroutine of some sort allowing you to use control flow logic inside it.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos first of all thank you. So, there is no work around for me to use to recall values from that CTE inside 1 of those MYSUBQUERIES?

Comment: Take out the parenthesis in your SELECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really doubt, that this is the best approach... You tried to clean and shorten this for brevitiy (thumbs up for this!), but the given information is - maybe - not enough.

You cannot use a `CTE` in different queries. A `CTE` is fully inlined as part of the query...

But you could write your values into a table variable like here:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Column1 INT, Column2 VARCHAR(100)); --Choose appropriate types
INSERT INTO @tbl  
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB FROM SomeTable WHERE ColumnA=SomeValue;
```

This table variable can be used in later queries (but in the same job!) like any other table:

```
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable AS st
INNER JOIN @tbl AS tbl ON ...
```

... or similiar usages...

Another approach might be this

```
SELECT Column1,Column2 INTO #SomeTempTable FROM SomeWhere
```

This will write the result of the `SELECT` into a temp table (which is session wide).

I'm quite sure, that there might be a better (set-based) approach... Are the two sub-queries identical in their result set's structure? If so, you might use `UNION ALL` and place your "`IF EXISTS`" as a `WHERE`-clause to each sub query.

Comment: Excellent, I believe that will do. Tnx a lot, learnt something new today too.

Comment: @DeepDiver I'm glad to help you! Happy Coding!

Comment: ...it seems you know where I am going...yes, the 2 subqueries are identical in the result sets structure...the subquery1, which is run when a record exists, returns different counts and sums. The subquery2, which is run when no record exists, needs to return 0 values.
Would you mind adding your example on using the UNION ALL and WHERE IF EXISTS? Tnx.

Comment: @Shnugo...can't give you enough kudos...after some attempts, I succedeed to get exaclty what I need with your tips.
This is a rather complex query that runs across the master, on the database of each customer and builds a report.

Answer (score 2):

`IF` is control flow.  `WITH` is within a query.  You can do:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT ColumnZ FROM AnotherTable WHERE Columnz=SomeNumbers)
BEGIN
    WITH MYCTE_TABLE (Column1,Column2)AS 
        SELECT (ColumnA, Column B FROM SomeTable WHERE ColumnA=SomeValue)
    MYSUBQUERY1
END;
ELSE
BEGIN
    WITH MYCTE_TABLE (Column1,Column2)AS 
        SELECT (ColumnA, Column B FROM SomeTable WHERE ColumnA=SomeValue)
    MYSUBQUERY2
END;
```

Or you could use a temporary table or table variable to store the values.

Comment: many thanks, it seems a temp table is the way forward. Steep learning.